# Find the tan of the three angles in the triangle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

M and N are midpoints of BC and AC. We know that tanφ = m. 
[image]

Find tanα and tanβ. (α and β are like usual the angles in the triangle)

Comment: What do you yourself know in the context?

Comment: You have  tanφ = m. You know m so you should find tanα and tanβ.

Comment: Any ideas about what you could do?

Comment: No man ,sorry. I do not have any idea.

Comment: Ok - I will try to help you then. But first I need to know where the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are. Please insert these into the picture. And it would be helpful if you included the context from where you found the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let $[ABC]$ be the area of $\triangle ABC$,
$|BM|=|MC|=a$,
$|AN|=|NC|=b$,
$|AB|=c$, 
$\tan\phi=m$.

Then
\begin{align}
c&=2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
,\\
[CAB]&=2ab
,\\
[CNM]&=\tfrac12ab
,\\
[ABMN]&=\tfrac34[CAB]=\tfrac32ab
,\\
[ABMN]&=
\tfrac12\,|AM|\cdot|BN|\,\sin\phi
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
|AM|&=\sqrt{a^2+4b^2}
,\\
|BN|&=\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}
,\\
[ABMN]&=
\tfrac12\,\sqrt{(a^2+4b^2)(4a^2+b^2)}\,\sin\phi
=\tfrac32ab
,\\
(a^2+4b^2)(4a^2+b^2)\sin^2\phi
&=9a^2b^2
,\\
\sin^2\phi&=\frac{9a^2b^2}{(a^2+4b^2)(4a^2+b^2)}
\\
\frac{m^2}{m^2+1}
&=\frac{9(\tfrac ab)^2}{((\tfrac ab)^2+4)(4(\tfrac ab)^2+1)}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\tan\alpha,\ \tan\beta
&=
\frac{3\pm\sqrt{9-16\,m^2}}{4m}
=
\frac{3}{4m}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac3{4m}\right)^2-1}
.
\end{align}

Comment: How do we make such neat triangle diagrams?

Comment: @Narasimham: This one was created with [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Let side $AC=b$ and side $BC=a$. Let angle $CAM=\theta$.

Drop perpendiculars from $G$ onto sides $AC$ (to point $X$) and to $BC$ (to point$Y$). $GY$ and $GX$  have lengths $\frac a3$ and $\frac b3$ respectively due to the property that the centroid $G$ divides the median $AM$ or $BN$ in the ratio $2:1$.

Then, in triangle $ACM$ we have $$\tan\theta=\frac{\frac a3}{\frac{2b}{3}}=\frac{a}{2b}$$

We also have in triangle $GXB$ $$\tan(\theta+\psi)=\frac{\tan\theta+m}{1-m\tan\theta}=\frac{\frac{2a}{3}}{\frac b3}=\frac{2a}{b}$$

$$\implies \frac{a}{2b}+m=\frac{2a}{b}(1-\frac{ma}{2b})$$

Now write $\tan A=\frac ab=k$. Note that $\tan B=\frac1k$.

Therefore $k$ satisfies the quadratic $$2mk^2-3k+2m=0$$

The roots are $$k=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{9-16m^2}}{4m}$$

Furthermore it is simple to show that if $k=\tan A=\frac{3+\sqrt{9-16m^2}}{4m}$, then $\tan B=\frac 1k=\frac{3-\sqrt{9-16m^2}}{4m}$